# Office 365 and Microsoft Graph login error

Tags: azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Additional technical information:

```
Correlation ID: 6cb0857c-7e6e-4cb9-95d2-9af7b6ba5768
Timestamp: 2015-12-26 21:55:23Z
AADSTS50020: User account 'harrypearson95@gmail.com' from external identity provider 'live.com' is not supported for application '8a3eb86b-8149-4231-9ff3-3c50958ea0fd'. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant. Please sign out and sign in again with an Azure Active Directory user account.
```

I get this error when trying to sign in on the microsoft api explorer website : https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net/

Answer (score 1):

Using https://graphexplorer2.azurewebsites.net you can only login using Office 365 accounts for work or school (that in most cases end with @onmicrosoft.com or custom enterprise domains).
The error above is from trying to login using an @gmail.com account. 
There is a version of the graph explorer that we will make available soon that will also support login with Microsoft Accounts (personal consumer accounts that in most cases end with @hotmail.com, @live.com and @outlook.com).
Please try using an Office 365 account to use the graph explorer to access your Office 365 data using the Microsoft Graph API.